# How to update text of attributedString in UILabel without affecting styles

Tags: ios, interface-builder, nsattributedstring

I have a UILabel whose look is defined in IB using "Attributed". I am updating the labels with text fetched at run-time.
If I update the label's .text property in code, the attributes are gone. Likewise if I create a new `NSAttributedString` for setting to  the label's attributedText property, I would need to know the style attributes. How can I retrieve the existing style attributes from the string/label? I don't think we are supposed to  define the style attributes twice, in IB and then in code as well?

Update: This is how I'm doing it now. It seems to work. Note that the UILabel is part of a UICollectionViewCell in a UICollectionView. The code is a bit bloated, but it seems to work. I make a new mutable attributed string using the existing string, then replace the characters. Also because this is part of a collection view interface, I can't just unset the text or something when there is no text for that cell, because I guess that would remove the style as well. So I just set the label to hidden when there is no text, preserving the style.

```
if (mytextstring != nil) {
    NSMutableAttributedString* newthing = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:cell.label.attributedText];
    [newthing replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, newthing.length) withString:mytextstring];
    cell.label.attributedText = newthing;
    cell.label.hidden = NO;
}
else {
    cell.label.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `myTextField.attributedText` to get the `NSAttributedString`. Use the `mutableString` property of the `NSMutableAttributedString` to modify the initial string.

Comment: `mutableString` property of a `NSMutableAttributedString` object is readonly, can't be set.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I couldn't find such a thing in the documentation. Then I would use the methods of the class, like `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` or `deleteCharactersInRange:`. Like you already do it... I couldn't find anything better than that.